# How does cookie come from AJAX based request populate page's cookie?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cookies

I'm wondering how does cookie come with AJAX requests interacts with page's one. Lemme explain how I understand the logic there:

There are some cookie come with a page itself ("page cookie"). When I make AJAX requests the page cookie are sent with request to the server and say server's changed something in the session (in rails session passed through cookies), hence cookies are changed.

Here's my question: is the changed cookies that came as AJAX response overwrite page cookies values?

Comment: There is no such thing as a “page cookie”. There is not even such a thing as a “page” ... HTTP doesn’t know of any “pages”, that imaginary construct has no meaning whatsoever. There are only URLs, and cookies can be specified as valid for certain URL paths.

Comment: Cookie namespace is decided by its domain and path (set by `Set-Cookie` header, not the page URL), there is no such thing as "cookie which belongs to one page"

Comment: Cbroe is totally right. Something that can help you though: if a browser has a cookie set with a given name, for a given domain and path, and receive another for the same settings, that will overwrite the first cookie.